# Getting data in dropdown list from DB in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables in my database one is `users` and another one is `requirements`. So I have `user_id` in the `requirements` table. I want to get `user_id` in the requirements page dropdown list.

Here is my Controller code:

```
public function requirement() {
    $data['user']=$this->LoginModel->getusers();
    $data=array(
        'role_name'=>$this->input->post('role_name'),
        'vacancies'=>$this->input->post('vacancies'),
        'experience'=>$this->input->post('experience'),
        'jd'=>$this->input->post('jd'),
        'hiring_contact_name'=>$this->input->post('hiring_contact_name'),
        'hiring_contact_number'=>$this->input->post('hiring_contact_number'),
         'user_id'=>$this->input->post('user_id')
    );
}
```

Model code:

```
function getusers() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result();
}
```

View code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Vendor</label>
    <select id="user_id"  class="form-control"  data-placeholder="user name"  name="user_id" >
        <option value="0"></option>

        <?php foreach($user as $rows) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rows->user_id?>"><?php echo ucfirst($rows->first_name)?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

I got error in foreach loop

> undefined variable data

please anyone help me..

Comment: print_r($user) in your view and check data come in array or not

Comment: no still it shows error undefined variable data

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query();this query is workign fine in my database..problem is in view page only

Comment: put this print_r($data['user']) after $data['user']=$this->LoginModel->getusers(); and check data array come or not or but top of this $data= array();

Comment: we can put  any where in view right? print_r($data['user'])

Comment: no @AslamPatel still got same error

Comment: put this code in controller  after $data= arra() code $data['user']=$this->LoginModel->getusers();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use this function

```
    public function requirement() {
$this->load->model(LoginModel');
    $data['user']=$this->LoginModel->getusers();
$this->load->view('your_view_page',$data);
}
```

Comment: print_r($data) and check

Comment: print_r($data); exit; and see the result

Comment: in controller after this $data['user']=$this->LoginModel->getusers(); print_r($data); exit; check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 

    public function requirement() {
$this->load->model(LoginModel');
   $data=array();
    $data['user']=$this->LoginModel->getusers();
    $data=array(
        'role_name'=>$this->input->post('role_name'),
        'vacancies'=>$this->input->post('vacancies'),
        'experience'=>$this->input->post('experience'),
        'jd'=>$this->input->post('jd'),
        'hiring_contact_name'=>$this->input->post('hiring_contact_name'),
        'hiring_contact_number'=>$this->input->post('hiring_contact_number'),
         'user_id'=>$this->input->post('user_id')
    );

$this->load->view('your_view_page',$data);
}
```

Comment: then use my last ans

Comment: do u have any idea like..is there any way to select multiple options at same time and save in database